# Node JS on Apache2 server not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, apache, p5.js

I recently followed the video series (p5.js lessons 12.1-12.4) by Daniel Shiffman (The Coding Train on YouTube). It was about using nodejs and socket.io to create a multi-user interactive drawing.

I wanted to take this project from the local server, as was done in the tutorial, and transfer it to an Apache server I just started running on my pi, with a domain from no-ip.com. I have messed around with putting the files in different place, but I can't seem to get the server to run.

Since the extent of my knowledge is from those videos, assume I know next to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need Apache server to run your node applications. you can use [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module or [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to create servers using node

Comment: I already have Apache2 and express installed, but can you explain how.?

Comment: I already know how to do that, I am curious of how to get it to work on my website running off of my Pi